# Unity PlayerPrefs issue in build mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a skill tree for my game, I'm using Unity's PlayersPrefs to save the state of the skills, everything works fine in the Unity editor, but as soon as I build, most of the skills are unlocked and some (in the middle of the tree) are still locked.

I tried to clear the playersPrefs in unity, to remove the PlayersPrefs in the build file, I gave them defaults values.
I was expecting that in build mode, all the skills would be locked but they were'nt, they were almost all unlocked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Remember to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise we have no way to know what is happening in your local code.